# Vector conjugate of a linear mapping

Tags: matrices, analysis, convex-analysis, vector-analysis

As we know, if $f:X \to \mathbf R$ is given by $f(x)=\langle a^*,x\rangle$, where $a^*\in X^*$ then the (Fenchel) conjugate of $f$ is given by $f^*(x^*)=0$ for $x^*=a^*$ and $f^*(x^*)=+\infty$ else.

Now let $f:\mathbf R^n \to \mathbf R^m$ be a given mapping and $K\subset \mathbf R^m$ a proper, closed, convex, pointed and solid cone. The (weak) vector conjugate $f^*$ is now defined by the following relation, where $V\in \mathbf R^{m\times n}$: $Vx-f(x) \in f^*(V)$ if and only if $Vx-f(x)  \not\leq_{\operatorname{int} K} Vy-f(y)$ for every $y\in \mathbf R^n$. Here, $a \not\leq_{\operatorname{int} K} b$ if and only if $b-a \notin \operatorname{int} K$.

> I would like to calculate the vector conjugate of $f:\mathbf R^n \to \mathbf R^m$, given by $f(x)=Ax$, where $A \in \mathbf R^{m\times n}$ is a given matrix.

It is easy to check, that $f^*(A)= \{0 \}$. Of course, this follows from the relation $Ax-f(x)=Ax-Ax=0$ and the fact that $0 \not\leq_{\operatorname{int} K} 0$.

> But how can I calculate $f^*(V)$ for $V\neq A$?

If needed, we can take the cone 
$$K:= \Big\{ y\in \mathbf R^m \mid \displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^{m} y_j \geq 0 \text{ and } y_j \geq 0 \text{ for } j=1, \dotsc, m-1 \Big\}.$$

Comment: What is $X$ in "for every $y\in X$"? And what is $Y$ in "$K\subset Y$"?

Comment: Sorry! It was $X= \mathbf R^n$ and $Y=\mathbf R^m$. I fixed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, $Vx-Ax \in f^*(V)$ if and only if $(V-A)(y-x) \not\in{\operatorname{int} K}$ for every $y\in \mathbf R^n$. Note that this condition is independent of $x$! Let us therefore replace $y-x$ with $y$ for convenience, and let us look at the opposite condition: there exists $y\in \mathbf R^n$ such that $(V-A)y \in{\operatorname{int} K}$. For your cone, this opposite condition holds if and only if there exists a $y\in \mathbf R^n$ and an $\varepsilon \in \mathbf R$ such that
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\ \vdots \\0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} (V-A)y \geq \varepsilon e, \varepsilon > 0,$$
or
$$\begin{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\ \vdots \\0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & \cdots & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} (V-A) & -e\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}y \\ \varepsilon\end{pmatrix} \geq 0, \quad \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ \vdots \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}^T \begin{pmatrix}y \\ \varepsilon\end{pmatrix} < 0,$$

We now invoke Farkas' lemma:

> Exactly one of the following statements is true:
>
> 1. The system $Az = b$ has a solution $z \geq 0$
> 2. The system $A^Ty \geq 0$, $b^Ty < 0$ has a solution $y\in \mathbf R^m$

We recognize the second statement in our linear system above. That was the opposite condition. Therefore, $Vx-Ax \in f^*(V)$ if and only if there exists a $z \geq 0$ such that

$$(V^T-A^T) \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 1 \\ \vdots \\0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} z = 0, \quad e^Tz = 1.$$
You can always rescale a nonzero $z$ such that $e^Tz = 1$, so all you need to know is whether
$$(V^T-A^T) \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 1 \\ \vdots \\0 & 0 & \cdots & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
has full rank. If it has, there is no such $z$ and $f^*(V) = \emptyset$. Otherwise, $f^*(V) = \{(V-A)x : x \in \mathbb R^n \}$ (which is the column space of $V-A$).

Comment: Thank you for your great answer! Have a great day!

Comment: @Niklas re-reading my answer, it seems like I forgot about the condition z≥0. Checking whether a system has a nonnegative solution is unfortunately more complex. The simplex method can be used for that. Applying Farkas' lemma does not have an advantage anymore, since you could as well use the simplex method to find an interior point (by maximizing $\varepsilon$ subject to $[[I \; 0]; e^T](V-A)y \geq \varepsilon e$).